# How to select with "partial information"

Tags: jquery, html-select

I have this select list:

```
<select id="ddTratte">
    <option value="">Text A</option>
    <option tratte="1523" value="14510">Text B</option>
    <option tratte="1524#1634" value="14534">Text C</option>
    <option tratte="1830" value="14510">Text D</option>
</select>
```

and the "partial" value I have is 1524. I need to select the 3° option, with `tratte=1524#1634`

How can I do it in jQuery? My actual code is:

```
$("#ddTratte option[tratte='" + "1524" + "']").val()
```

but this is exclusive. How can I select it?

Comment: `tratte` isn't a valid HTML attribute. If you want to use custom attributes you should prefix it with `data-`: `data-tratte`.

Comment: Where is written this?

Comment: `<option tratte="1523" ... >`

Comment: I mean: where is written that I can't use `tratte` instead of `data-tratte`?

Comment: In your question... The HTML you've provided has 3 `option` elements all with an invalid `tratte` attribute. You should change this to `data-tratte` if you want your HTML to be valid.

Comment: But WHO write that HTML is valid only if the prefix is "data". The rules of HTML are so stupids imo, in the next 2 months could be that the default prefix will be `data2014-tratte`

Comment: It's part of the HTML5 specification: http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes

Comment: HTML5... born years ago, and will not be a standard imo...NEVER!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`*=` attribute selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors):

```
$("#ddTratte option[tratte*='1524']").val()
```

As I mentioned in my comment on your question though: `tratte` isn't a valid HTML attribute. If you want to use custom attributes you should prefix it with `data-`:

```html
...
    <option data-tratte="1524#1634" ... >
...
```

Then select using:

```
$("#ddTratte option[data-tratte*='1524']").val()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this ^=

```
$("#ddTratte option[tratte^='1524']").val()
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
    <select id="ddTratte">
<option value="">Text A</option>
<option tratte="1523" value="14510">Text B</option>
<option tratte="1524#1634" value="14534">Text C</option>
<option tratte="1830" value="14510">Text D</option>
   </select>


var $value  = $('#ddTratte').children().eq(2).text();
alert($value);
```

The fiddler is here :
http://jsfiddle.net/eWMmG/